# Learning EF Code First: What are the disadvantages compared to model first?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm thinking about moving from EF model first to code first. The advantages look clear enough to me and it seems quite intuitve to use.
What are the disadvantages compared to model first? What pitfalls must I suspect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is set of disadvantages:

- You must write all code by yourselves
- You have lesser control over database generation
- You don't have support of Database power pack for incremental database development (code first have SQL migrations but they are still in beta and doesn't provide same feature set as power pack)
- You will lose some basic and almost all advanced mapping features (but those advanced features are usually not used with model first anyway).
- You will most probably use DbContext API

  - It will be new for you (unless you already use it with model first)
  - You will still have to revert to ObjectContext API in more complex cases because DbContext API is only for simplest tasks
  - It can have additional bugs and sometimes it has even worse performance than ObjectContext API
  - IMHO after several months of usage and following EF tags on SO I think it is still quite unmature

Anyway DbContext API is the mainstream. Since .NET 4.5 DbContext API will be Entity Framework and ObjectContext API will be Entity Framework Core libraries. It definitely means that DbContext API is what ADO.NET team wants to push forward.

Comment: Thanks for that summary. So the bottom line might be, that code first is more for rapid/short term development and model first if you want to cover all eventuallities long term..